# What is rule of this function?

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, interpolation

I have these values.these are inputs and outputs of a function.I want to find rule of function.input is N.

```
    N             f(N)
   512           0.000
   1024          0.001
   2048          0.003
   4096          0.011
   8192          0.042
   16348         0.154
   32768         0.572
   65536         2.134
   131072        7.864
   262144        29.190
   524288        108.301
   1048576       400.578
   2097152       1482.995
```

Comment: It was much better without image and with actual numbers typed in.

Comment: What are you try to model? Did you try building a plot of this function? In linear scale or in logarithmic one? What does it look like? Do you have an idea on the dependence. Finally, one can always build a polynomial that passes through these points.

Comment: Hint: Both $N$ and $f(N)$ grow exponentially (as a function of list position).

Comment: I think it is logarithmic.

Comment: You should have started by plotting the points on a graph. And also try a log-log plot (now we know that you would have got a straight line).

Comment: Free software include scilab, gnuplot or even python (with matplotlib e.g.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I observe that the left column is obviously exponential, and the right column seemingly so.  (Each item in the right column is somewhat more than three times the previous item.)  So it makes sense to construct a log-log plot of the data:

[image: log-log plot of data]

The $x$-axis is the logarithm of the left-hand column, and the $y$-axis is the logarithm of the right-hand column.

At this point it is obvious that the relationship between the logarithms of $x$ and $y$ is linear, so  $\log y = m\log x + b$ where $m$ and $b$ are the slope and $y$-intercept of the plotted line.  Linear regression gives $m\approx 1.88$ and $b\approx -20.086$:

[image: log-log plut with regression line]

So we can write  $$\begin{align}y & = e^{1.88\log x - 20.086}\\ & = \frac{x^{1.88}}{529108792}\end{align}$$

Checking $x=65536$ we get $y=2.145$ which is close to the $2.134$ in the table; had I rounded off the $1.88$  more carefully we might have gotten a more accurate result.  The apparent zero value for $x=512$ is actually around $0.00023$.

For the linear regression I used [a tiny program](https://github.com/mjdominus/util/blob/master/bin/lr) that I wrote in Perl a few years ago, but any handheld scientific or financial calculator will do it. I explained it in detail [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131590/linear-regression/131602#131602).

Comment: The x-axis is the logarithm of the left-hand column, and the y-axis is the logarithm of the right-hand column.what is the base of logarithm?10 or 2

Comment: I used base $e$, but it doesn't matter which you use; all logarithms are really the same function, with a different scale.  The graph would look the same and have the same slope if I had used base 10 or base 2, and the slope of the line would have been the same.  Notice how the base of the logarithm disappears from the relationship between $x$ and $y$ in the formula $\frac{x^{1.88}}{529108792}$.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ***cftool*** in MatLab to interpolate, the function that you want.

Comment: I have not `MatLab`.

Comment: you can use from the below website to interpolate it: http://www.solvemymath.com/online_math_calculator/interpolation.php